# C# списки и объекты класса

Tags: c#

есть написанный класс списка с базовыми функциями, и есть класс point который добавляется в сам список и имеет собственные методы. После добавления в список нескольких объектов, в цикле пытаюсь вызвать метод Print у класса point, но ничего не получается, может кто знает как решить эту проблему?

класс узла

```
 public class Item<T>
{
    private T data = default(T);
  //данный хранимые в ячейке списка

    public T Data {
        get { return data; }
        set { if (value != null)
                data = value;
        }
    }
    //следующая ячейка списка
    public Item<T> Next { get; set; }

    public Item(T data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Data.ToString();
    }





}
```

сам список и класс point

```
public class List<T> : IEnumerable
{//первый элемент списка
    public Item<T> Head { get; private set; }//голова
    //последний элемент списка
    public Item<T> Tail { get; private set; }//хвост
    //кол-во элементов
    public int Count { get; private set; } //кол-во элементов
    //конструкторы
   //создать пустой список
    public List()
    {
        Clear();
    }
    //создать список с начальным элементом
    public List(T data)
    {

        SetHeadAndTail(data);
    }

    //добавить данные в конец списка
    public void Add(T data)
    {

        if (Tail != null)
        {
            var item = new Item<T>(data);
            Tail.Next = item;//указатель хвоста зацепили за следующий
            Tail = item;
            Count++;

        }
        else
        {
            SetHeadAndTail(data);
        }
    }
    //удаление
    public void Delete(T data)
    {
        if (Head != null)
        {
            if (Head.Data.Equals(data))
            {
                Head = Head.Next;
                Count--;
                return;
            }

            var current = Head.Next;
            var previous = Head;



            while (current != null)
            {
                if (current.Data.Equals(data))
                {
                    previous.Next = current.Next;//смена указателя
                    Count--;
                    return;
                }
                previous = current;
                current = current.Next;
            }
        }
    }

    private void SetHeadAndTail(T data)
    {
        var item = new Item<T>(data);
        Head = item;
        Tail = item;
        Count = 1;
    }
    //получить перечисления всех элементов списка
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        var current = Head;
        while (current != null)
        {
            yield return current.Data;
            current = current.Next;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Linked List"+Count +"элементов";
    }

   public void PrintPoint()
    {
        point p = new point();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}   {1} ",p.X,p.Xname);
    }
    //очистка списка
    public void Clear()
    {
        Head = null;
        Tail = null;
        Count = 0;
    }
    //добавить в начало списка
    public void AppendHead(T data)
    {
        var item = new Item<T>(data)
        {
            Next = Head
        };

        Head = item;
    }

}

public class point 
{
    public point()
    {

    }
    public point(int xx,string str)
    {
        X = xx;
        Xname = str;
    }
    public int X { get; set; }
    public string Xname { get; set; }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("X " + X + " name " + Xname);
    }
}
```

мейн функция

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<point>();
        list.Add(new point(1, "dadadad"));
        list.Add(new point(2, "dadadad"));
        list.Add(new point(3, "dadadad"));
        foreach(var p in list)
        {
            //тут проблема
            p.
        }



    }
```

Comment: `но ничего не получается` как это понимать?

Comment: Реализуйте интерфейс `IEnumerable<T>` в вашем классе `List<T>`.  Простой `IEnumerable` возвращает `object`. Либо в foreach делайте явный каст к типу: `foreach (point p in list)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы реализовали необобщенный (не-generic) интерфейс `IEnumerable`. Компилятор не может вывести из `IEnumerable` тип перебираемого объекта. Вам нужно или реализовать `IEnumerable<T>`, или явно тип указать:

```
foreach (point p in list)
{
    p.Print();
}
```